# Hi could someone explain the behavior of this simple c# async program

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Hi please look at this example code. It works as expected when running a synchronous and asynchronous method `TaskString()` and `TaskString2()`. I.e. the program executes them together and writes them out to the console screen. If a 3rd asynchronous call is introduced `TaskString3()` then it seems to jump out before it can write out to the console. This can be run as a simple console app, thanks. How can this behavior be explained?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Async
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            TaskString();

            TaskString2();

            //TaskString3();
        }

        private static async Task TaskString()
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Method 1: " + i);
                    // Do something
                    await Task.Delay(200);
                }
            });
        }

        private static void TaskString2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Method 2: " + i);
                // Do something
                Task.Delay(100).Wait();
            }
        }


        private static async Task TaskString3()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Method 3: " + i);
                    // Do something
                    Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify a language. Looks like C#. Is it?

Comment: The language is c#.

Comment: Ok, so the code is pretty convoluted. But baseline is: `TaskString2()` is blocking, while `TaskString3()` is not. So, as soon as TS2 returns, TS3 will return a Task, which is not awaited and thus probably the program will be terminated before the passed Action in TS3 has a chance to be started.

Comment: Correct. Do not use Wait(). But it's not the issue, here. You see `TaskString()` output by coincidence, because the main thread is executing `TaskString2()` concurrently.

Comment: Thats making more sense sense thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Console programs exit when the main method returns, or in case of async Main, when the returned task completes. So while `TaskString2` is running, any background tasks are kept alive and running. `TaskString3` starts a new background task, but once started, the main method is done and can return, and this will shutdown the process, killing any background tasks still running.

To fix it you should be able to just await the tasks. i.e.

```
     var t1 = TaskString();
     TaskString2();
     var t3 = TaskString3();
     await Task.WhenAll(new []{t1, t3});
```

This will ensure the main method returns a task that only completes when all the background tasks have finished.